# Stuck with an Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have a scenario like this: there is a table `course_details` as below:

[image: course_details]

Now what I am looking for is to find the details of students - in this case `Stu_id` - who have enrolled in courses in 2016.

Say for example - for 2016 there are course C1,C3 and C4. Of these courses only S1 has enrolled in all of them. S2 and S3 has enrolled only in some.

So my query should give only the result as S1.

I tried using subquery factoring, window functions, but unable to get it without hard-coding some values.

Comment: Is there a list of course IDs in some other table?  How do we know there isn't a `C5` or a `C6`?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what details you're looking for?

Comment: Also, please show us code that you have tried and why it's results didn't match what you wanted.

Comment: This is just a sample data set. I have given this table only for illustrative purpose and provided the use-case as an example as to what exactly I'm looking for

Comment: It's confusing that your problem statement says "students who have enrolled in courses in 2016" and then your example says something about being "enrolled in all of them" which wasn't in the problem statement. Try to clear that up.

Comment: I can get the list of courses for say - 2016.

select c_id from course_details where enrol_dt = '2016';

This query would give me 3 courses(c1,C2,C4) - in the above case. This is where I get stuck. How do I match these courses will all the students. Like S1 should have taken C1, C2 and C4 (I'm not bothered about the year they took the course) and similarly S2 and S3.

Comment: How does your schema represent the existence of a course that nobody has enrolled in yet?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley -This just a small excerpt of the schema.

Comment: @FirstName, so you are saying you want to find a student who took all courses offered in 2016, regardless of what year the student enrolled in the course?

Comment: @DavidAman Yes, thats exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.stu_id
FROM course_details AS a
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL FROM course_details AS b
        WHERE
            b.enrol_dt = 2016
            AND
            NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM course_details AS c
                WHERE c.c_id = b.c_id AND c.stu_id = a.stu_id
            )
    );
```